# Inserting in a script bash multiple lines with "find" each with its own command "-exec" an error is signaled on "-exec": missing argument

Tags: bash, find, exec

I have to search with "find" different files and directories and on each search result different commands "-exec" must be executed so I need to use in the script more lines with "find": each line executed individually not by error and actually comes executed, if instead I insert all the lines in a single script the error "find: missing argument to '-exec'" appears.

This is the example of the script I should run:

```
#!/Bin/bash
find /var/www/html -type d -o -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/html/tolda/vendor -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: The lines that you show do not produce any error. Please add an example of a find that produces the error message.

Comment: Here `#!/Bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash`. Though I haven't tested rest of code.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but I should warn you about that the first find command doesn't do anything on directories, it just skips them

Comment: And I can't reproduce the error here, did you try running `dos2unix 00-permessi.sh` before running the script? You know, to remove carriage returns

Comment: #!/Bin/bash ... I typed the characters wrong but it was correctly written in the script  #!/bin/bash while for dos2unix it tells me dos2unix: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I entered these two lines in a script named:
00-permessi.sh
When I run the script with bash 00-permessi.sh on the linux terminal the error appears:
"find: missing argument to 'exec'

If I delete one of the two lines leaving only one, the command is executed correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/html -type d -o -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/html/tolda/vendor -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/html -type d -o -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

is executed correctly

idem is executed correctly

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/html/tolda/vendor -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

[screenshot terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktiz6.png)

**I finally understood the problem!**
Editing the file with a normal text editor and transmitting it with FTP at the end of each line, **the line break was inserted**.
Opening the file with **vi** and deleting the forward character and saving the script is executed without errors.